# How to use Thread-Local Storage in linux kernel module?

Tags: linux, ssl, kernel

I'm making a Linux kernel module that separates threads.
Each thread needs a global variable, so I tried to use Thread-Local Storage using the __thread keyword. However, because it is a feature supported by GCC, I found that the __thread keyword is not supported by kernel modules compiled with Kernel Makefile.
Is there any way to use Thread-Local Storage on Linux kernel modules?

Comment: There is no support for Thread-Local Storage inside Linux kernel. All per-thread data you want to have should be added as fields into `task_struct` (this will require to recompile the whole kernel). But because Linux kernel is rarely creates threads by itself, per-thread data are rarely actually needed. You could provide more details about your purpose, so we could be able to suggest better approaches.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Is there anything a kernel module could do to allocate & initialize thread-local memory in such a way that it'll get cleaned up (in the way the module author specifies) at thread exit/death?

Comment: @PSkocik: I cannot imagine thread-local memory support without thread-local variables. And as I said above, thread-local variables are not supported in the Linux kernel.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Stack is a kind of thread local storage. Just declare your "thread global variables" as the entry function's local variables.